# Sum in laravel db query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I need to get the Sum of **ProductQTY** groupBy **ProductID** while using join, I always get an error when using `db::raw`, attached here is my code

```
$pick_list_items = DB::table('pick_list_detail')
                   ->where('pick_list_detail.pick_list_id',$id)
                   ->join('sale_invoices', 'pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','sale_invoices.id')
                   ->join('sale_invoice_detail', 'sale_invoice_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id')
                   ->select(['pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id', 'sale_invoice_detail.product_id', 'sale_invoice_detail.product_qty', 'sale_invoice_detail.uom', 'sale_invoice_detail.uom_factor'])
                   ->sum('sale_invoice_detail.product_qty')
                   ->groupBy('sale_invoice_detail.product_id')
                   ->get();
```

I'm using laravel **5.4**

Here is the error

> (2/2) QueryException
>       SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'fdis.pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select
>   `pick_list_detail`.`sale_invoice_id`,
>   `sale_invoice_detail`.`product_id`,
>   `sale_invoice_detail`.`product_qty`, `sale_invoice_detail`.`uom`,
>   `sale_invoice_detail`.`uom_factor` from `pick_list_detail` inner join
>   `sale_invoices` on `pick_list_detail`.`sale_invoice_id` =
>   `sale_invoices`.`id` inner join `sale_invoice_detail` on
>   `sale_invoice_detail`.`sale_invoice_id` =
>   `pick_list_detail`.`sale_invoice_id` where
>   `pick_list_detail`.`pick_list_id` = 1 group by
>   `sale_invoice_detail`.`product_id`)

[image]

Comment: what is your error

Comment: Plz provide some relevent code

Comment: @Giovanni Error already attached

Comment: @MahdiYounesi error added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $sale_invoices = DB::table('pick_list_detail')
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(sale_invoice_detail.product_qty) as si_count, pick_list_detail.pick_list_id , sale_invoice_detail.product_id , sale_invoice_detail.uom, sale_invoice_detail.uom_factor '))
    ->where('pick_list_detail.pick_list_id',$id)
    ->join('sale_invoices', 'pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','sale_invoices.id')
    ->join('sale_invoice_detail', 'sale_invoice_detail.sale_invoice_id','=','pick_list_detail.sale_invoice_id')
    ->groupBy('pick_list_detail.pick_list_id')
    ->groupBy('sale_invoice_detail.product_id')
    ->groupBy('sale_invoice_detail.uom')
    ->groupBy('sale_invoice_detail.uom_factor')
    ->get();
```

Raw Query is my solution.